# kafka file stream with limitation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

am trying to extract the file from string input from a file, I am having stream connector running throughout the day, but am facing below issues,

1, The file has more than 20k records(20K lines), when a new file is recognized, the connector posts the message up to 10k and then goes to idle. does the connector has any limitations/configuration to limit the data? am checking this count from the topic(which is configured at source.properties) console consumer. (as soon as job started, I saw another window with consuming the messages with diff consumer group).

2. My file connector keeps running through our the day, file(abc.txt) data is published to the topic and tries to replace the new file (remove the current file from a location and place same file name with diff data set), the running job is getting an exception, but when I append the new data set to the existing file, it is running fine. is it an excepted behavior?

any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more details - which connector, what configuration, what version, etc?

Comment: Version # Confluent Platform: 5.1.2

Comment: its from standalone mode,

Comment: key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

Comment: Please edit your question to include these details, it makes it much easier for people to see. Can you also edit your question to include the connector configuration itself (you've quoted the worker config)

Comment: connect-file-source.properties
name=local-file-source
#connector.class=FileStreamSource
connector.class=com.us.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
file=/Users/vettri/projects/confluent-5.1.2/etc/kafka/test.txt
topic=connect-json-topic-converter

Comment: connect-standalone.properties
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

Comment: What is `com.us.file.FileStreamSourceConnector`? I suggest you contact the developers of that class to find limitations in it...